# java function that changes negative number to 0

Tags: java

Is there a built-in function in java that would convert any negative number to a 0? what i'm wanting to do is subtract number from a variable, and ensure that it doesn't go below 0. is this possible with built-in functions or would i have to write my own?

Comment: Use  `Math.max(0, yourVar)` (I can't decently make an answer from that...)

Comment: @dystroy You can post this as an answer, so that OP can accept it.

Comment: @RohitJain I'm not sure this should be my most upvoted answer of the day...

Comment: BTW how to name this function that returns only positive or zero? I think about this names
toNaturalNumber()
ceilToZero()
toZeroOrPositive()

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You should use :

```
 Math.max(0, yourVar)
```

You don't need a built-in function for that.

Comment: oh, duh! i've used min before, but I never thought of max! thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You do not need any function to turn a negative into a zero. You can use a conditional declaration of the variable and turned the negative value into a zero.

In a conditional declaration, what goes before the question mark is the condition. If the condition evaluates to true, the first value after the question mark would be assigned to the variable.

If the condition evaluates to false, the value that goes after the column will be assigned to the variable. In the case below, a would be assigned the value of itself if it does not carry a value that is below zero.

```
int a = -1;
a = a < 0? 0 : a;
```